# Git erroneous no-op merge

Tags: git, github, merge, squash

I'm seeing a weird merge-failure in Git following a "squashed" merge-to-master.

I've created a [tiny GitHub repo](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/git-merge-failure) to reproduce the issue.

Essentially, the process is as follows:

- I created two branches.
- In one branch, I made [two](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/git-merge-failure/commit/d2d6e997fc3553e75652bb480916cecb967b072e) [commits](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/git-merge-failure/commit/d32e6bc7cc91296d8cb91444d0adf38bd7d90bc4).
- I merged these commits into a second branch.
- I [`merge --squash`'d these commits into master](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/git-merge-failure/commit/4d9fe9c68c3f7d0bbe503126a1eddf684cb01df0).
- I [deleted a file directly on the master branch](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/git-merge-failure/commit/ffe3ee9e60f3bf021e103ce0e20483533b33e8a3).
- I then [merged the changes in master back into the original branch](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/git-merge-failure/commit/a3371f9c1dacde44ad3cae5c14bc86f6999317fb).

  - This is where the problem occurs. This merge produces **no changes** to the branch. The file that was deleted on master is still present.
- I pulled everything on this up-to-date branch into the second branch.
- I opened a [pull request](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/git-merge-failure/pull/1) to demonstrate that merging the second branch into master will re-introduce the previously-deleted file.

What's going on here? Why doesn't the merge from master back into the branch include the change made directly to the master branch? Is this a bug or a use-error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug. The problem is that your [squash commit](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/git-merge-failure/commit/4d9fe9c68c3f7d0bbe503126a1eddf684cb01df0) is not a merge, so git doesn't know that it is connected to `Branch-1`. It sees it as an ordinary commit. When you merge `master` into `Branch-1`, git sees that there were following changes since those branches diverged:

- in `master`: added `file1` and `file2`, then deleted `file1`. Overall diff: added `file2`.
- in `Branch-1`: added `file1`, added `file2`. Overall diff: added `file1` and `file2`.

Git merges branches using those overall diffs. You added `file2` in both branches, but there is no merge conflict, because `file2`s from both branches are identical. So the outcome of the merge is a commit, containing both `file1` and `file2`.

For the same reason your pull request will add `file1` to `master`.

But if you've done a real merge instead of a squash, the result would be as you expect.

---

Actually, this is even mentioned in [git help merge](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html):

> With the strategies that use 3-way merge (including the default, *recursive*), if a change is made on both branches, but later reverted on one of the branches, that change will be present in the merged result; some people find this behavior confusing. It occurs because only the heads and the merge base are considered when performing a merge, not the individual commits. The merge algorithm therefore considers the reverted change as no change at all, and substitutes the changed version instead.

Comment: Huh. I have previously noticed that in cases like this where `master` has `squash`d changes from a branch, and a second branch has unsquashed changes from the same branch, merging the "squash" commit back into the original branch and then merging that new "merge" commit back into the second branch seems to prevent merge errors that would otherwise arise from pulling directly from master. I thought this was because during the merge-from-master-to-original-branch, the "squash" commit was somehow given special treatment--

Comment: but it sounds like I should get the same behavior (i.e. avoid the merge conflicts) by simply pulling from Branch-1 into Branch-2 without pulling from master into Branch-1.

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question (was it even a question?), but, yes, git should not force you to resolve conflicts, when both sides introduce the same changes (because it doesn't matter which side you will pick - the result will be the same).

Comment: I guess the implicit question was "are you sure squash-commits aren't ever given any special treatment during merges?"

Comment: Yes, I am sure. But keep in mind, that "conflict-free merge of equal diffs" works only if diffs are equal (actually, not the whole diffs, I think, but individual potentially conflicting hunks). Example: if you add `123` to a `file` in `branch1`, then squash that commit to `master`, then create `branch2` from `branch1` and change `file` there to contain `456`, it will get tricky. Merge of `master` into `branch1` will complete without conflicts (diffs are equal), and then merge of that new `branch1` into `branch2` will also complete without conflicts (diff will be empty)...

Comment: ... But if you instead merge `master` directly into `branch2`, there will be a conflict, because diff `added '123'` is not equal to diff `added '456'`, and git doesn't know (doesn't care), that `added '456'` is actually `added '123'` + `changed '123' to '456'`. Still, no special treatment for squash commits.